# Doubt about the history of the tensor object in physics

Tags: tensor-calculus, history

The word "tensor" (or, maybe the whole physical idea of this object) could be traced date to 1898 on the work on Crystals due to Voigt [1]. It seems that the references [2] and [3], introduce the idea that tensors in physics firstly appeared in 1898, but, you may ask yourself: and how about other quantities like inertia tensor? I mean, the idea of a tensor could be dated to 1898 but a tensor character of a quantity it's in the equations since 1700 at least (e.g. the physics of rigid bodies and the inertia tensor). So, which was the first occurency of a tensor property in physics?

$$ * * * $$

[1] Voigt, Woldemar (1898). Die fundamentalen physikalischen Eigenschaften der Krystalle in elementarer Darstellung [The fundamental physical properties of crystals in an elementary presentation]

[2] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woldemar_Voigt

[3] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor#Spinors

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2030558/what-is-the-history-of-the-term-tensor